# GitHub pages returning error 304 for react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages, react-router-dom

I have a very simple app where I am `React Router` in `React`, which is then getting deployed on `GitHub Pages` but I am noticing the following error: `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app (Error: 304)`. I noticed that if I take out the Router component and just display `<HomePage/>` then everything works fine.

What could be the reason behind this happening?

Thanks in advance.!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Homepage setUserData={setUserData} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

`GitHub Pages` don't work with `<BrowserRouter>`. I think if you replace it with `<HashRouter>`,  the component will be rendered without an error.

```js
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```